# fstream file("arr.txt") raise error "corrupted double-linked list, Aborted" on Ubuntu14.04 but works well on Windows 7

Tags: c++, ubuntu, window

```
void read_file_into_2d_array(const string file_name, int row, int col)
{
    float data[row][col];
    std::ifstream file(file_name);

    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(file, line);
        if(!file.good())
            break;

        std::stringstream iss(line);

        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
        {
            std::string val;
            std::getline(iss, val, ' ');
            if (!iss.good())
                break;

            std::stringstream convertor(val);
            convertor >> data[row][col];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string file_name = "arr.txt";
    read_file_into_2d_array(file_name, 3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

> corrupted double-linked list, Aborted(core dumped)

I build my project successfully, but when I run it, it raise an error "corrupted double-linked list, Aborted(core dumped)" on Ubuntu 14.04. Whereas it works well on Windows 7. The compiler on Ubuntu is g++, and mingw32-g++.exe on Window. I don't know what is the problem?

Comment: C++ doesn't support variable-length arrays.

Comment: but why it work successfully on Windows?

Comment: Because your compiler allows this as an extension.

Comment: The variable-length array issue has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: yeah, now I have modified float[row][col] into float[3][4], but it does not work either

Comment: Maybe you have problems in other parts of your program, and they could be causing the corruption.

Answer (score 1):

You make a big chance to cause crash by doing out-of-range access in the line

```
convertor >> data[row][col];
```

try this instead:

```
convertor >> data[i][j];
```